# Redshift Copy Command - how to specify ESCAPE and QUOTE as'"'?

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have a file that I am trying to load into redshift using the copy command.  This file already has quotes escaped at source.  I cannot change the how the source file is created.  This is the type of line that is causing a problem which results in "Invalid quote formatting for CSV error"

1234,1,,"A",,false,"Some text "some more, text" some more text"

The command I am using is

COPY my_table FROM my_s3_file credentials 'my_creds'
CSV
IGNOREHEADER 1
ACCEPTINVCHARS;

I have tried removing the CSV option so I can specify ESCAPE with the following command

COPY my_table FROM my_s3_file credentials 'my_creds'
DELIMITER ','
ESCAPE
IGNOREHEADER 1

but then the comma in the middle of a field acts as a delimiter.  I feel like the quotes around the field are not being recognised

Is there anyway to load this file using the COPY command?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with CSV format / option for this case as there is a documented and widely used specification on how to format the data in such cases. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180

If I understand the case in question you have double quotes and commas inside fields in the file.  The specification states that you need to escape the double quote (use double double quotes for double quotes) inside a field. Changing your line to

1234,1,,"A",,false,"Some text “"some more, text”" some more text"

I believe you can succeed down the path you are on (plain text files instead of CSV) by escaping the quotes with backslashes ().  Like this

1234,1,,"A",,false,"Some text \"some more, text\" some more text"

I just prefer CSV as the spec has clear ways to handle these corner cases and making up new file rules usually leads to unexpected “next” corner cases. Either way you go you will need to change the data in your files to add one escaping or the other.

PS. Don’t copy paste the above as the website is changing plain characters to specials.